# How can I run a command with values ​in python sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
 if message.content.startswith("!Cooltime"):
        con = sqlite3.connect("Hamal.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"SELECT CoolTime FROM UserInfo WHERE DiscordId = {message.author.id}")
        exist = cur.fetchone()
        #------here--------
        if exist == 100:
            print(1)
        if exist == 200:
            print(2)
        #-----------------
```

I select "Cooltime"columns where the "DiscordID" is the message author's DiscordId
but, it doesn't working at "here"

And here is the sqlite3 Db

| CoolTime | DiscordID |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | (user's id 1) |
| 200 | (user's id 2) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchone()` ALWAYS returns a tuple, even when there's only one column.  Use `exist[0]` to extract the first/only column.

And, by the way, the simple debugging step of printing the intermediate result would have told you this at once.